# Using COM References after deplyoing on IIS Server

Tags: image, asp.net-core, powerpoint

I developed a simple powerpoint conversion (into images) to display them in a caroussel.
So I used the

> Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

On my devlopment environment it works fine but when I publish it with Azure on my IIS Server, it seems that id does not work.

> Exception:
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80040154

Why does it works before the deployment on IIS ?
I tried to install powerpoint on the server without succes, could you give me hints ?

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft neither recommends nor supports using PPT or other Office programs on a server. I vaguely recall a server-level setting that allows PPT to run interactively, which wouldn't be the default in a server environment. That can fix some problems at the server end; sorry I can't recall the exact name of the setting.

Comment: So should I develop an application using JavaEE or any other language than call it using my ASP.Core application ?

Comment: Or can't I just install office / PowerPoint on my server ?

Comment: If you're going to ask PowerPoint to do the heavy lifting, then you'll need to install it, but as I mentioned, there are issues around running it on the server. As to developing an application, you'd basically be creating your own version of PowerPoint. Seems like a bit of a task. Another option would be to put a regular PC on the network, give it access to the server drive where incoming PPT files are stored, write code to "watch" the directory and do the export to images there on the non-server PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was too much of a hassle to use Microsoft COM :
HRESULT_FAIL + Not all clients have Office + Office Server etc

so I just use this : https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/presentation/presentation-to-image

Free Trial can be used multiples times or you can get a licence key for free.